# Why can I no longer connect to my NAS using cifs

Tags: networking, samba, cifs, nas

This is curious, it stopped working on my **VirtualBox** Linux using **lubutu** 20.0.4 and my **Ubuntu** machine 20.04.04 at the same time. I am able to connect with Windows with no problem. However, when I use the following either mounted to my **NAS** with a script or like my **/etc/fstab**.

```
//10.0.0.xxx/Volume_1 /home/rp/Documents/DLINK.Volume_1 cifs vers=1.0,username=admin,password=


//10.0.0.xxx/Volume_2 /home/rp/Documents/DLINK.Volume_2 cifs vers=1.0,username=admin,password=
```

I even have the **vers=1.0** which worked before also

and do a **sudo mount -a** when it worked before. I get now

Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

I have installed smbclient and checked the shares after adding two lines in the **/etc/samba/smb.conf** file under **[globals]**

client min protocol = CORE

client max protocol = SMB3

I get with

sudo **smbclient -L //10.0.0.xxx**

Enter WORKGROUP\root's password:

```
Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
Volume_1        Disk      
web_page        Disk      Enter Our Web Page Setting
lp              Printer   USB Printer
Volume_2        Disk      
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (DNS-323)
```

Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

```
Server               Comment
---------            -------
DESKTOP-xxxxx      
DLINK-xxxxxx         DNS-323
RP-xxxxxxx           rp-xxxxxxxx-M77 server (Samba, Ubuntu)

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
WORKGROUP            DLINK-xxxxxxx
```

I have tried everything on the internet unsuccessfully. Please help me resolve this issue

Comment: I use cifs to access a Synology NAS. My fstab line for the main share is //192.168.1.117/share_name /media/NAS/share_name cifs username=user_name,password=psw,rw,uid=1000,gid=500 I created the mount points separately.

Comment: Have you tried `smbclient -L //10.0.0.xxx -U admin`? Specifying the user `admin` that you use in your `/etc/fstab` file ... Do you see the shares with that user specified?